# Passing SSIS parameters from Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

I'm trying to create a Job that will run my SSIS project.

In my project, I have 3 user-defined parameters, `startDate,endDate,shiaruchDate` .

I've been searching online for a while but couldn't locate an answer that will help me.

I'm creating a new job, then created a new step, but the `Parameter` tab is empty and I can't fill anything. Where and how do I define the 3 parameters to be an input? Where do I need to specify this ?

Thanks .

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/sql-server-agent-jobs-for-packages

Comment: Reading the link and guessing.... you might need to define those parameters at the package level, not the project level.

Comment: I've already changed the scope of the parameters, it's now available when defining the job, my problem now is - how do I dynamically change them in each called? (E.G. exec <Job> Param1,Param2,Param3) . @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: You don't usually assign dynamic parameters in a job. Usually you'd work that out in the package (or a master package that calls this package). In what way do you want them to be dynamic?

Comment: This job should be available for a few employees in my company. They should be able to run the SSIS project(with the job or W\E) and provide 3 dates for the parameters, without being able to use SSIS .  @Nick.McDermaid Should I use another method to run the SSIS project ?

Comment: This is starting to sound like the wrong tool for the right job. Can they just edit the job? If not is it because they have no security to edit it or because it's too complex? How are they meant to know it's finished? You could for example write something that writes parameters to a table and starts the job. The package would read from the table. SSIS isn't really built for user interaction like that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using SSIS 2012 or above.

If you had user defined parameters you could use environment variables to configure the parameters in SSISDB.

This link has further info with screenshots, hope that helps.
http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/9/15/getting-started-with-parameters-variables-configurations-in.html

Cheers
Nithin

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After I do all this, how can I call the Job so I can manually populate the environment variables ?

Comment: you can create an environment variable using a GUI, more info at this link: http://mcr.aacrjournals.org/content/14/1_Supplement/A90 If you would like to use it for multiple environments, you coudl script it out and create different values for the variables depending on the 
 environment